# how to get CSSearchableItemAttributeSet in appDelegate

Tags: ios, corespotlight

```
NSMutableArray *searchableItems = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

    CSSearchableItemAttributeSet *attributeSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc]initWithItemContentType:@"vvv"];

    attributeSet.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"warwick%d",i];
    attributeSet.contentDescription = @"warwickDescriotion";
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"];
    attributeSet.thumbnailData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    CSCustomAttributeKey *lat = [[CSCustomAttributeKey alloc]initWithKeyName:@"lat"];
    [attributeSet setValue:@"123456789" forCustomKey:lat];

    CSSearchableItem *item = [[CSSearchableItem alloc]initWithUniqueIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"warwick%d",i] domainIdentifier:nil attributeSet:attributeSet];

    [searchableItems addObject:item];
}

[[CSSearchableIndex defaultSearchableIndex]indexSearchableItems:searchableItems completionHandler:nil];
```

I have set some `searchableItems` with a `customKey`, how can I get the `customKeyValue` in AppDelegate?

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you get in the `AppDelegate` `continueUserActivity` method is the unique identifier of the `CSSearchableItem` in the `userInfo` dictionary of `userActivity` and nothing else.